# How to simplify active record query in Ruby

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to filter based on country, city, state, role, and rate card. If user selects any single means or any combinations, it should work. This is my active record for search:

```
if params[:role].present?
  if params[:role] == 'role1'
    if params[:city_name].present?
      @matching_c = @matching_c.where(city_name: params[:city_name])
    elsif params[:state].present?
      @matching_c = @matching_c.where(state: params[:state])
    elsif params[:country].present?
      @matching_c = @matching_c.where(country: params[:country])
    end
    if params[:rate_card].present?
      @matching_c = @matching_c.joins(:rate_card).where("rate_cards.rate_card_type = ?", "#{params[:rate_card]}")
    end
    @matching_f = nil
  end
  if params[:role]  == 'role2'
    if params[:city_name].present?
      @matching_f = @matching_f.where(city_name: params[:city_name])
    elsif params[:state].present?
      @matching_f = @matching_f.where(state: params[:state])
    elsif params[:country].present?
      @matching_f = @matching_f.where(country: params[:country])
    end
    if params[:rate_card].present?
      @matching_f = @matching_f.joins(:rate_card).where("rate_cards.rate_card_type = ?", "#{params[:rate_card]}")
    end
    @matching_c = nil
  end
else
  if params[:city_name].present?
    @matching_f = @matching_f.where(city_name: params[:city_name])
    @matching_c = @matching_c.where(city_name: params[:city_name])
  elsif params[:state].present?
    @matching_f = @matching_f.where(state: params[:state])
    @matching_c = @matching_c.where(state: params[:state])
  elsif params[:country].present?
    @matching_c = @matching_c.where(country: params[:country])
    @matching_f = @matching_f.where(country: params[:country])
  end
  if params[:rate_card].present?
    @matching_c = @matching_c.joins(:rate_card).where("rate_cards.rate_card_type = ?", "#{params[:rate_card]}")
    @matching_f = @matching_f.joins(:rate_card).where("rate_cards.rate_card_type = ?", "#{params[:rate_card]}")
  end
end
```

This works, but I want it to be simplified. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: "If user selects any single means or any combinations, it should work" - but it doesn't - right now it only allows one of (city, state, country). Do you want combinations as well?

Comment: yes, it is working fine now, because if we selects city means no need of country and state combination right, it will give cities in that country and state only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def add_where(query, params)
  # FROM HERE
  field = %i(city_name state country).find { |x| params[x].present? }
  if field
    query = query.where(field => params[field])
  end
  # TO HERE

  if params[:rate_card].present?
    query = query.joins(:rate_card).where("rate_cards.rate_card_type = ?", params[:rate_card])
  end

  query
end

@matching_c = params[:role] != 'role2' ? add_where(@matching_c, params) : nil
@matching_f = params[:role] != 'role1' ? add_where(@matching_f, params) : nil
```

It will accept only one of (city, state, country), like your code. If you want to accept any combination, use this instead of the marked code:

```
%i(city_name state country).each { |field|
  query = query.where(field => params[field]) if params[field].present?
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You should chain scopes, not mutually exclude them:

```
@matching_c = @matching_c.where(city_name: params[:city_name]) if
  params[:city_name].present?
@matching_c = @matching_c.where(state: params[:state]) if 
  params[:state].present?
@matching_c = @matching_c.where(country: params[:country]) if
  params[:country].present?
```

Comment: In that case `@matching_c = params.slice(:city_name, :state, :country).reject {|_,v| v.blank? }.reduce(@matching_c) { |query,(field,val)| query.where( field => val) }`

Comment: @engineersmnky I realized the level of the OP and decided not to overcomplicate things :)